# Delete database row with specific value after 1 hour php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning on adding destroyable messages to my website.
I want users to choose how long the message should be 'alive'.
The message should be destroyed a specific time after creation only if the row meets a column value.

The important columns are:

`time, destroy`

time is stored as DATETIME in the database.

I want a row to be deleted 1 hour after creation only if destroy equals '1'

I'd highly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as I have no clue on how to approach this.

Thanks in advance

I've read about using cron jobs but I failed to do so.

This is what i've tried:

cron.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `d_msg_enc` WHERE `mode` = 1 AND `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW() INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? Because there is multiple way to achive this functionality.

Comment: I've read about using a cron job but I failed doing so I'll add it in the OP

Comment: Why not simply use an expiration date and use that to fetch the right records? You could configure a cronjob to cleanup the records that are past their expiration date.

Comment: Can't imagine why I haven't thought about that.. I got it to work now by using a expiration date and a simple cron job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not command php script to run after 1 hour (or schedule scripts) .. To accomplish this type of scheduling of scripts use CRONS..

Refer this url for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18737637/4419992